# Compatilibity level between 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have this error using MSMS 2008 trying to connect to SQL 2012. The problem is that the database under SQL 2012 has compatibility level: SQL Server 2008 (100)

https://support.powerdnn.com/kb/a1781/you-receive-errors-when-connecting-to-mssql-2012-using.aspx

My question is: when you restore a SQL 2008 db in SQL 2012, even if the database has compatibility level 2008, the db is converted to 2012 and we can't put it back again in a 2008 server again?

Comment: You still have the original SQL 2008 db backup file(s), right?  Just restore again into SQL 2008.

Comment: Yes I have it, but is something to keep in mine for the future in case client doesn't want to install 2012 and we continue developing in 2012

Comment: Ah, I see.  I agree with @Charleh.  It's a one-way proposition.  For development purposes, I'd keep that database on SQL 2008 and do your development there until your client upgrades to a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the database format is not backwards compatible as far as I know

What you can do is use the "generate scripts" functionality to script the entire database out in SQL2008 format and run that on a 2008 server to get a working 2008 version.

Depending on the size of the DB this may be impractical though